# Building tensorflow on raspberry pi

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, boringssl

I was building Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi 3, following the [installation guide](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md)

When I am running this command,

```
"bazel build -c opt --copt="-mfpu=neon-vfpv4" --copt="-funsafe-math-optimizations" --copt="-ftree-vectorize" --copt="-fomit-frame-pointer" --local_resources 1024,1.0,1.0 --verbose_failures tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package",
```

I am getting the error shown in figure.

[image]

Could anybody help me?